# Asympototic estimation of log log function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, logarithms, asymptotics

Let $N>0$ be an integer and consider the sum $\sum_{n=3}^N(\log \log N-\log \log n)$. It is not hard to see that this sum has the complexity $O(N^2)$ since $\log \log x <\log x<x$, so that the sum is smaller than $\sum_{n=3}^N N-n$. But can we find a better upper bound for this sum so that it has at most complexity $O(1)$? And what could be the best estimation of this sum?

Comment: Did any of us answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

By the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), we have
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n = 3}^N {\log \log n} & = \int_3^N {\log \log t\,\mathrm{d}t}  +  \mathcal{O}(\log \log N)\\ & = N\log \log N - \int_3^N {\frac{{\mathrm{d}t}}{{\log t}}}  + \mathcal{O}(\log \log N)
\end{align}
as $N\to+\infty$. Consequently,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 3}^N {(\log \log N - \log \log n)}  = \int_3^N {\frac{{\mathrm{d}t}}{{\log t}}}  + \mathcal{O}(\log \log N)
$$
as $N\to+\infty$. Finally, using the [asymptotic expansion of the logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion), we have
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 3}^N {(\log \log N - \log \log n)}  \sim \frac{N}{{\log N}}\left( {1 + \frac{{1!}}{{\log N}} + \frac{{2!}}{{\log ^2 N}} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $N\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I get that
the sum is bounded by
$N \ln(\ln(N))/\ln(N)
$.

What follows is not always rigorous,
but I think it has
a good chance of being correst.

$0 < a < 1,
a=e^{-1/c}$
so
$1/c=-\ln(a),
c=-1/\ln(a)
$.

$\begin{array}\\
f(n)
&=\sum_{k=3}^n (\ln(\ln(n))-\ln(\ln(k)))\\
&=\sum_{k=3}^{n^a} (\ln(\ln(n))-\ln(\ln(k)))+\sum_{k=n^a+1}^n (\ln(\ln(n))-\ln(\ln(k)))\\
&<n^a \ln(\ln(n))+\sum_{k=n^a+1}^n (\ln(\ln(n))-\ln(\ln(n^a)))\\
&<n^a \ln(\ln(n))+n(\ln(\ln(n))-\ln(\ln(n^a)))\\
&=n^a \ln(\ln(n))+n(\ln(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n^a)}))\\
&=n^a \ln(\ln(n))+n(\ln(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{a\ln(n)}))\\
&=n^a \ln(\ln(n))+n(\ln(\dfrac{1}{a}))\\
&=n^a \ln(\ln(n))+n(-\ln(a))\\
&=n^{e^{-1/c}} \ln(\ln(n))+n/c
\qquad 1/c=-\ln(a), a=e^{-1/c}, \ln(a)=1/c \\
&\approx n^{1-1/c} \ln(\ln(n))+n/c
\qquad \text{if } c \text{ is large} \\
\end{array}
$

If $c=n^{1/c}$,
so the terms are
approximately equal
(aside from the
$\ln(\ln(n))$)
$c^c=n,
c \ln(c)=\ln(n)$
so
$c \approx \ln(n)/\ln(\ln(n)),
n/c \approx n \ln(\ln(n))/\ln(n)$